# How to put javascript in html file

Tags: javascript, html

Let me re-explain the whole question.

I want to add this in my website http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

So for this, i have to make a external java file (internal may work, but i want external).

So when i paste the java code in my html file in body tag, the script works fine. So that means, nothing wrong with the script. But when i put the same thing in a different external file, the script is not working. 
So the problem must be in the head tag, where i write the external file location. This is my head tag

```
        <head>
<title>FFH</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/ffh.ico" />`
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Yes, the "myscript.js" is in the same folder and i am 100% sure about it.

Comment: Take a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: How exactly are you trying to add `myscript.js` to your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following can be a reason for your issue

1. Invalid src path in the script tag
2. Javascript might be disabled in your browser.
3. You have a script error/exception that stopped entire page's script execution.
4. Maybe you have an Ajax request that won't work if your open it as a local file protocol.  e.g., file://

What can you do? 
It is right time for you to know about and use your developer tools available in your favorite browser.

See if it shows 404 or some other error. Then update your SO question with the exact error message that you see. We would be happy to help.

**Revised answer based on provided w3c link:**
Now we know the exact problem. 
You can not add that script tag to the head of the HTML. Because the elements that you refer in the script are not available at that time of execution. Move the script tag just before the end of body tag (all your carousal tags/elements should be present before the script tag) . Then It would work as expected.

If you still want that script tag to be in the head section, then you have to initialize your carousal/slider in DOM ready event or window.Onload event.

Still my earlier comment is relevant,  because you can use **developer tools in your browser** to find out the exact error statement.

Comment: SRC path is right and script is also working. Edited my question, you may understand now.

Answer (score 1):

put your html file and javascript file under the same folder.

Comment: it is already like that. I can upload the folder, it;s 600kb, if u want.

Comment: try to put 
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">
in <body> </body>

Comment: It'll all depend on when certain parts of the code are executed. In your code above,  If they're in the header, then the elements they are attempting to access might  not exist yet.

Comment: did you try this ?



<body> 

------- your code -------

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">

</body>

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, script-tag may not work if it is located in `<head>` tag. Try adding it right before `</body>`.

+don't call it java, they have nothing else in common except name :)